# Sending JMS messages to either Topic or Queue by the same EJB - consume by single MDB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb, jms

On my way of learning JMS asynchronous messaging I have created a simple app.

There is a message producer (Stateless bean), that is sending messages to the Queue (configured on Wildfly 10). And a Message driven bean consuming the messages from the Queue. Also there is a servlet that calls the `"SendToQueue(MailEvent mailEvent)"` method of my message producer bean.

Now I have an idea to create another method `"SendToTopic(MailEvent mailEvent)"` in the same bean so that it could be called from another servlet.

- Is it the right approach to have one bean with two methods for sending messages to either Topic or Queue?
- And also is it OK for a single MDB to consume these messages? 
  What is considered the best practice in this situation?
- Is it a good idea to create an interface with `"SendToQueue(MailEvent mailEvent)"` and `"SendToTopic(MailEvent mailEvent)"` methods from the OOP perspective?

I'm just learning so may be missing something and will be grateful for any advice or critique.

```
@Stateless(name = "EmailSessionBean")
public class EmailSessionBean {

    public EmailSessionBean() {
    }

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/jms/queue/MyQueue")
    private Queue queue;

    public void SendToQueue(MailEvent mailEvent) {

    try {
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);

        ObjectMessage objMsg = session.createObjectMessage();
        objMsg.setObject(mailEvent);

        messageProducer.send(objMsg);
        out.println("Sent ObjectMessage to the Queue");
        session.close();

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**MDB**

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(
                propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(
                propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/jms/queue/MyQueue") })

public class EmailMDB implements javax.jms.MessageListener {
    @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/mail/Gmail")
    private Session mailSession;

    public void onMessage(Message message){
        try {
            if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                System.out.println("Queue: I received an ObjectMessage " +
                        " at " + new Date());
                ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
                MailEvent mailEvent = (MailEvent) objectMessage.getObject();

                InternetAddress fromAddress = InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(mailSession);
                String fromString = fromAddress.getAddress();

                javax.mail.Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

                //msg.setFrom(fromAddress);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromString,"From me to you"));
                InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(mailEvent.get_To())};
                msg.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
                msg.setSubject(mailEvent.getSubject());
                msg.setSentDate(new java.util.Date());
                msg.setContent(mailEvent.getMessage(), "text/html");
                System.out.println("MDB: Sending Message...");

                Transport.send(msg);

                System.out.println("MDB: Message Sent");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid message ");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with an EJB having two methods each one with its own business logic. Including sending to different queue. However, one thing that is discouraged from the specification is to have a single MDB listening to more than one queue. Each MDB should consume messages from a single destination.

Comment: @Leonardo What about creating an EJB local interface (no need for remote in my situation) and two implementing Stateless session beans: one with business logic to send messages to a Topic and another one sending messages to a Queue ?

Comment: If you mean two EJBs implementing the same interface, it is allowed. But in this case the client must specify which concrete implementation is required. However, if everything is local, I would go for no-interface view.